# Modelling 1 to Many relationships that repeats multiple times

Tags: database, database-design, relational-database, relationship

I have three tables `Initiative`, `Category` and `Forecasts`. The relationship is 1 to many across all tables.

`Initiative` can have multiple `Category` can have multiple `Forecasts`

`Initiative` can be either recurring or not based on which the `Category` names can be different. For example for a recurring `Initiative` it will have a set of specific `Categories` that will repeat for all `Initiatives` of recurring type.

And forecasts will be per category for months of the year.
This is how it is currently and the fiddle is [here](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/fwowJQDRDCumsgdwz6r2M1/2)

[image]

The thing with this approach is that for each initiative of a particular type the category name is repeated that many times although it is the same.

Another problem with this is when we need to add an initiative of a particular category we will have to maintain another AllInitiative table with all the Initiative and all the Categories to map them initially to the `Category` table. After which forecasts can be added to the newly added initiative and category.

How do I better design this structure so that I have one `AllInitiative` table which has all types of initiatives exactly once and an `AllCategory` table which has a list of Categories for each type of Initiative.

And use another table to keep track of a particular type of initiative and category without duplicating category names across each instance of a particular type of initiative.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the `Initiative` table, with all initiatives once, another one for `Category`, and for 1-n relationships you need a linking table for example `Initiative_Category` in which you have foreign keys for initiative and category.

In this table you can store each initiative with the corresponding categories.

```
    +---------------+-------------------+
    | initiative_id |    category_id    |
    +---------------+-------------------+
    |       1       |         2         |
    |       1       |         3         |
    +---------------+-------------------+
```